# Transferring charge from one body to another

Tags: electrostatics

There is a question in my textbook,

> Can ever the whole excess charge of a body P be transferred to another body Q? Explain.

I know that if both P and Q are conductors, then enclosing P by Q would transfer the net excess charge from P to Q, since the net charge on a conductor resides on its surface. Correct me if I'm wrong.

The question does not constrain what type of substances P and Q are ( i.e. conductors or insulators)

But Would it be possible to transfer the charge if

1) P is a dielectric?

2) Q is a dielectric?

3) Both P and Q are dielectrics?

What would happen in each case?

Comment: By *dielectric* do you mean *insulator*?

Comment: @JohnRennie Yup

Comment: What do you think would happen?